# Looping into Object to filter it comes out that sometimes works and sometimes not Angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am developing a friend logic in my code.
For example two users can be friends with each other.
The 1 user sends a request to 2 user and the 2 user it is notificated that someone added you as a friend.
Then the 2 user accept it.
But If I iterate from 1 user to 2 user and I check if they are friend sometimes works and sometimes not.
The problem is that even I am friend it says to me again to `Add as friend` which is not the case I want.
But sometimes If I reload page then it works.
Be aware `this.data.user` is the ID of the `friend`

In the request I am handling to get me the whole friends maybe there is the problem why it does this.

This is my code for checking if they are friends or not which is called at `ngOnInit`.

```
 checkFriend: User[] = [];

  if(success[1]) {
          this.data = success[0];
          this.checkFriends(this.data.user);
} else {

      this.modelDataService.getUserModel(this.outsideUserId).subscribe((t: Model) => {
        this.data = t;
        this.loadActiveUserConnections(this.data.user);
        this.checkFriends(this.data.user);
}
this.modelDataService.getOutsideModel(this.outsideUserId).subscribe((t: Model) => {
            this.data = t;
            this.loadActiveUserConnections(this.data.user);
            this.checkFriends(this.data.user);
    }  //The problem occurs here because here both are called from otuside


 checkFriends(id) {
    this.friendService.getAllFriendRequests().subscribe((finalRequesters) => {
      this.checkFriend = finalRequesters;
      this.checkFriend.forEach((oneRequest: any) => {
        console.log(oneRequest);
        if ((oneRequest.friendId === id || oneRequest.friendId === id) && oneRequest.status === "You are friend") {
          oneRequest.isFriend = true;
          this.isFriend = true;
        } else if (oneRequest.friendId === id && oneRequest.status === "Request Pending") {
          oneRequest.uniqueId = oneRequest.userId;
          oneRequest.isRequest = true;
          this.isRequest = true;
        } else {
         this.isFriend = false;
         this.isRequest = false;
        }
      });
    });

  }
```

This is the HTML code.

```
   <a class="px-1" *ngIf="!checkUser">
      <button class="px-3 font-weight-600 btn btn-light" (click)="addFriend()" *ngIf="!isFriend && !isRequest">
        <span class="bi bi-person-plus-fill d-flex align-items-center">
          <span class="pl-2">Add Contact</span>
        </span>
      </button>
      <button class="px-3 font-weight-600 btn btn-light" *ngIf="isRequest">
        <span class="bi bi-person-plus-fill d-flex align-items-center">
          <span class="pl-2">Cancel Contact Request</span>
        </span>
      </button>
    </a>
```

And this is the request.

```
getAllFriendRequests() {
  return this.http.get<any[]>(this.apiBaseURL + "/friends");
}
```

This is how `oneRequest` looks like.

```
  { createdDate: "2021-03-20T22:24:54.512Z"
    friendId: "602e4c30e3346466703376ab"
    id: "605676360fb6b109209674be"
    status: "You are friend"
    userId: "5fbc1bc72ffec245c4bd7725"
    __v: 0
    _id: "605676360fb6b109209674be"
    __proto__: Object}
```

`friendId` is the friendID, `userId` is the authenticated User.
But If I try to console log the `oneRequest` it is giving me back whole array of objects not only the object indeed.

And this is how in backend looks like.

```
  async showUserCV(req, res) {
        ModelData.aggregate()
        let modelData = await ModelData.findOne({userUrl: req.params.id }).populate("user").exec();
        if (!modelData) {
            res.status(204).json({error: "No Data"});
            return;
        }
        return res.status(200).send(modelData);
    },

const ModelData = require("../models/data");
```

Comment: is it possible to provide a stackblitz with mock data?

Comment: @AakashGarg I will try it.

Comment: @AakashGarg But it will be hard -_-, because the code it is so large.
But I will give my best.

Comment: just try to reproduce mock scenario with minimal possibility.

Comment: It's just an idea, but try to call `this.checkFriend = finalRequesters.body` in the subscribe function since you are getting a HttpResponse.
(https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse)

Comment: @matsch It will not work because "Property 'body' does not exist on type 'any[]'.ts"

Comment: @Abedin.Zhuniqi Ah yeah... my bad

Comment: @AakashGarg I found the problem where it is but I don't know how to fix it -_-.
The problem it is that, I do have different exceptations.
1. When in the webb app when I search users and I go to user it works but If I copy the link and paste in new Tab then it will create these conflicts.
But I need to get the data from backend with different urls.
For example with ID and with the userUrl which are not the same.
So I dont have any idea how to handle this now.
Because both of them are called from outside I mean direct as link.
See my updated code.
And as in Stackblitz I did some code.

Comment: where is stackblitz url?

Comment: @AakashGarg Here is the url https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r2pbsx

Comment: why don't you call apis sequentially to operate data in order?

Comment: @AakashGarg what do you mean ?

Comment: @AakashGarg because they call different apis in backend.
  `public getUserModel(id) {`
    `return this.http.get<any>(`${this.baseUrl}/data/${id}`);`
  }`
  `public getOutsideModel(id) {`
    `return this.http.get<any>(`${this.baseUrl}/data/user/${id}`);`
  }`

Comment: @AakashGarg This is happening I think because the request with `userUrl` it is responsing me back at first time with undefined.
Look for new changes in the code and I added a part of backend code

Answer (score 0):

If u want to loop to overwrite the data, u can use map() instead of forEach().
Try this:

```
this.checkFriend.map((oneRequest: any) => {
  // Put what u want to do in loop here
}
```

Comment: @Svanthna `map` it will not work, I have tried that.
The problem occurs when I entry the page from new tab or at reload page.